# Assign values in table from vector

Tags: r, assign

In R have a table containing a set of insect species and an empty column "habitat specifity". Additionally, a vector specifies those species considerated habitat specialists: Species B and C are habitat specialists, species A, D and E are habitat generalists.

```
example.species <- data.frame (species = c("A","B","C","D","E"), habitat.specifity=NA)
example.species
  species habitat.specifity
1       A                NA
2       B                NA
3       C                NA
4       D                NA
5       E                NA
example.specialists <- c("B","C")
```

I simply want to fill column two ("habitat specifity") with "s" for specialist and "g" for generalist. The table should then look like this:

```
  species  habitat.specifity
1       A                  g
2       B                  s
3       C                  s
4       D                  g
5       E                  g
```

I think it must be a simple task to accomplish, but I cannot figure out how. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Try `example.species$habitat.specifity <- ifelse(is.na(match(example.species$species,example.specialists)),"g","s")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straightforward way in base R:

```
example.species <- data.frame (species = c("A","B","C","D","E"), habitat.specifity=NA)
example.species$habitat.specifity <- "g" # default value
example.species$habitat.specifity[example.species$species %in% c("B","C")] <- "s"
#   species habitat.specifity
# 1       A                 g
# 2       B                 s
# 3       C                 s
# 4       D                 g
# 5       E                 g
```

Comment: this works perfectly. However: there is one thing I do come accross from time to time, but honestly don't understand: what does the "%" mean? Sorry for this greenish question...

Comment: In R operators of the form `%op%` are called infix operators, `%in%` is the most common one, along with `%/%` and `%%`. You can also define your own. The `%` sign doesn't mean anything by itself here. More info here: https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/infix-operator/

Answer (score 1):

Example with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

# Your data
example.species <- data.frame(species = c("A","B","C","D","E"),habitat.specifity=NA)

# Simple if_else with dplyr and pipes
example.species %>%
  mutate(habitat.specifity = if_else(species %in% c("B","C"), "s", "g"))

# Result 
  species habitat.specifity
1       A                 g
2       B                 s
3       C                 s
4       D                 g
5       E                 g
```